# Qt/QML unable to make getOwnPropertyDescriptor working

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I'm in trouble with Qt 5.7.0 and QML. I need to discover properties of some objects at runtime.

The goal is to use a pure QML tree view found elsewhere. This one was build with hardcoded properties to hold the values to display. It's a very simple treeview and it's just what I need. Using Controls 2.0 I have no "stock" TreeView.

My goal is to change the pure QML TreeView to give him the object tree and the proprty names instead of hardcoded ones.

I do not want to use a full Qt model to have a lightweight component.

Leaving that goal appart one can sometime have to dynamically ask for a property value only knowing it's name at runtime. In C# and Java for example it's easy to use reflection to do that.

Coming from C# world I'm looking for the same concept. In my usecase the objects will not be pure QML ones but C++ ones exposed by qmlRegisterType.

I plan to use **Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor** but I can't make it works as I want, after hours of test...

Here is a POC in pure QML/JS

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {

   id: myTest

   property int myProp : 1234


   function test() {
      console.log("_________________TEST_________________");
      console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myTest))
      console.log(myTest.hasOwnProperty("myProp"))
      console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(myTest, "myProp"));
      console.log("_________________TEST_________________");
   }
}
```

In the log I get:

```
qml: _________________TEST_________________
qml: [objectName,parent,data,resources,children,x,y,z,width,height,opacity,enabled,visible,visibleChildren,states,transitions,state,childrenRect,anchors,left,right,horizontalCenter,top,bottom,verticalCenter,baseline,baselineOffset,clip,focus,activeFocus,activeFocusOnTab,rotation,scale,transformOrigin,transformOriginPoint,transform,smooth,antialiasing,implicitWidth,implicitHeight,layer,myProp,objectNameChanged,childrenRectChanged,baselineOffsetChanged,stateChanged,focusChanged,activeFocusChanged,activeFocusOnTabChanged,parentChanged,transformOriginChanged,smoothChanged,antialiasingChanged,clipChanged,windowChanged,childrenChanged,opacityChanged,enabledChanged,visibleChanged,visibleChildrenChanged,rotationChanged,scaleChanged,xChanged,yChanged,widthChanged,heightChanged,zChanged,implicitWidthChanged,implicitHeightChanged,update,grabToImage,grabToImage,contains,mapToGlobal,mapFromGlobal,mapFromItem,mapToItem,forceActiveFocus,forceActiveFocus,nextItemInFocusChain,nextItemInFocusChain,childAt,myPropChanged,test]
qml: true
qml: undefined
qml: _________________TEST_________________
```

According to the line "qml: true" the "hasOwnProperty('myProp')" find the property and say "true".

But the next line trying to get the property descriptor return "undefined".

The one who can solve my problem will be my Hero !

Comment: So the properties are not defined as `readonly` are they? A short snippet, how I need to imagine the structure of the `TreeView` would be nice. As long as `hardcoded` is not `readonly` (in C++: there are no setters) it should be doable.

Answer (score 1):

feel like a noob... I discovered I can query properties by name with *myobj[propertyName]* syntax.

too easy to be seen before...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the property descriptor you need to set it before.

```
Item {
    id: myTest
    property int myProp : 1234

    function test() {
        console.log("_________________TEST_________________");
        console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myTest))
        console.log(myTest.hasOwnProperty("myProp"))
        console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(myTest, "myProp"));
        console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(myTest, "myProp").value)
        console.log(myProp)
        console.log("_________________TEST_________________");
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        Object.defineProperty(myTest, 'myProp',
                              {
                                  enumerable: false,
                                  configurable: false,
                                  writable: false,
                                  value: '50'
                              })
        test()
    }
}
```

But IMHO it is completely useless. So maybe it would be good **to expand on your final goal** as this question of yours is most likely one of those [*infamous XY-Questions*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Ok, I guessed the property definition already creates a descriptor. I add detail about the final goal

Comment: I made a test in JSFiddle, therefore in pure Javascript, and it's working as I guessed. It seems QML/JS not defining the property or something like that.